# Powershell - O365 Migration script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am using the following Syntax, to Migrate user`s and create O365 mailboxes in our organization:

```
# Mailbox Migration Script

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;

$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session 

Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity user.name -PrimarySmtpAddress user.name@company.com -RemoteRoutingAddress user.name@company365.mail.onmicrosoft.com

sleep 30

# After the initial script has done running, run the following:

Get-RemoteMailbox  user.name|Set-RemoteMailbox -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled:$true
```

Everything works ok , but what i would like to do is to convert this, so the data is being read from a CSV file instead so that the actual wont have to be touched.
Im guessing this should be with the import-csv, unfortunately i don`t know what the rest of the syntax should be.

The exact data i need to acquire via csv is the following:

-Identity user.name

-PrimarySmtpAddress user.name@company.com

-RemoteRoutingAddress user.name@company365.mail.onmicrosoft.com

Each part of the data should be acquired from a column in the CSV.

Please assist with creating this script.
Thanks a bunch , in advance to all.

Answer (score 0):

You're right -- [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) is the ticket here.

```
$ExchangeData = Import-CSV -path C:\MyExchangeData.csv 

# Access the data to IMPORT each user.
# Assumes the CSV has "Email, UserName, RemoteEmail" as headers.

foreach ($user in $ExchangeData) {
     Enable-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user.UserName -PrimarySmtpAddress $user.Email -RemoteRoutingAddress $user.RemoteEmail
 }
```